# Toggle application with NFC

Tags: nfc

I am using NFC tag to run Car application, and to set volume up in car on my HTC M8. But after I go out of the car I must to manually close application and set volume down.
Please, is there a way how to create task to toggle application and volume setting(if app is not running start it, when app is running close it)?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try an automation app like [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) (free) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid).